# How to add photo/logo in Flutter Vcard

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I am designing a new Digital vcard, Name, phone, address etc. it generate Qrcode when we scan that all the details is import to mobile phone device but i am not able to upload photo/ logo. how can I merge uploaded photo to vCard. Please guide and suggest I am new to Flutter.

I want to generate QRcode with vcard details. everything is working fine but facing issues to import uploaded image, when I scan QRcode all the details are directly import to contact with help of Vcard plugin. but I failed to import image from QR code via vcard.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this? https://pub.dev/packages/vcard_maintained

Comment: @Aks yes I tried and currently I am using this vCard_maintained plugins Only, but it showing Errors like this : The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = '' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: I guess you are using picked image path as vcard.photo. Try to convert that image in bytes then store in vcard.photo and when you try to get data from vcard > create image from those bytes.

Comment: @Aks,okay I will check. one more help, I want to share generated QrCode as a image I added share_plus plugins and its working but it only sharing vCard text field like Name, phone, email etc.. not  Qrcode image? what's the issue I am not getting

Comment: I am using a package screenshot: ^1.3.0 to take a screenshot and then I am able to send this image using share_plus plugin. But there's a problem in ios devices. I can only send image or text at one time using share_plus plugin. Working fine in Android devices. Here's is the link for code imgur.com/a/aC5q1sb

Comment: @Aks I'm facing issues and errors, If you have any Example code file please share the link.

Comment: you need example code for vcard or creating qr code and share?

Comment: @Aks I need qrcode and share, actually I created Vcard now it is working fine it generating qrcode. but I'm facing issues during share it sharing qr code backend data like  name: , phone: , email: , etc but I  want to share generated Qrcode as a Qr image.

Comment: Checkout the answer and update the title of your question :)

Comment: @Aks I got output, It's Working thank you so much.

Comment: @Aks I am not able to understand this error. how to solve please help Errors : The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = '' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Aks Hi, if possible can you please share me the Example code for To fetch the data From Api by get by id method.  we user create Vcard the data will store in DB and id is also generated for every entries. the data I need to fetch and display in next page. I'm not able to fetch data.  Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Aks postgres database

Comment: It'll be good if raise another question regarding your problem while using postgres databbase.

Comment: @Aks I raised question, Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the generated qr code.
Add path_provider, screenshot packages

//Define a controller for screenshot

```
ScreenshotController controller = ScreenshotController();
```

//Wrap your QrImageView with Screenshot

```
Screenshot(
            controller: controller,
            child: QrImageView(
              data: data,
              foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
              backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
              embeddedImage: image,
              eyeStyle: QrEyeStyle(
                eyeShape: eyeShape,
                color: foregroundColor,
              ),
              dataModuleStyle: QrDataModuleStyle(
                dataModuleShape: dataModuleShape,
                color: foregroundColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

//Now on click of a button

```
 IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final list = await controller.capture();
            //controller.capture() will capture the widgets wrapped inside Screenshot()
            if (list != null) {
              final directory = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
              File imgFile = File(
                  '$directory/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');
              imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(list);

              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              await Share.shareFiles(
                [imgFile.path],
                text: 'hi this is the text',
              ).catchError((e) {
                debugPrint('Error: $e');
              });
            }
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.send))
```

//working in android but in ios only text or image can be share at one time